# Do I need Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0 to update my app

Tags: xcode, swift, legacy-code

I have an UI issue in my Swift 1 (Xcode 6, iOS 7.1) app on devices running iOS9. I've tried to convert my app to Xcode 7 and Swift 2.0 but I'm running in a lot of issues here.

To give my customers a quick fix until I've figured out whats wrong I was wondering if I can download and install Xcode 6 (the version I build and uploaded the app last time) correct the UI issue (I know what to do) and upload the app again.

In a nutshell: Will Apple deny an app update with an old Xcode/Swift version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [“Submit Your Apps” page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submit/) currently (as of 2015-09-23) says

> If your app still depends on Xcode 6, you'll need to keep a partition or external hard drive with OS X Yosemite installed in order to submit from Xcode 6.

This clearly implies that you can still submit apps with Xcode 6 (and therefore with the iOS 8 SDK).

Comment: Side note: That seems to be directed to developers working on an El Capitan machine. If you're still on Yosemite, you can run Xcode 6 and 7 side by side (Xcode 6 and El Capitan don't seem to play well with each other).

Comment: Is it literally only for submitting apps to the App Store? Can you still build apps on El Capitan with Xcode 6, be it via Xcode itself or `xcodebuild`? I'm think what would happen to build servers needing to run Xcode 6 but wanting to run El Capitan..!

Comment: I believe Apple means that Xcode 6 cannot run on El Capitan. If you want to run Xcode on El Capitan, you must use Xcode 7. If your build servers need to run Xcode 6, you must run Yosemite on your build servers.